# Removing Duplicate Rows from All Spreadsheets in a Folder using Google API Scripts

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates
This link shows removing duplicate rows from specific spreadsheet. I have folder and sub-folders in goolge drive. I want to remove duplicate rows from each individual spreadsheet in the folder and all sub-folders. In brief, the procedure in the link is to be repeated for all spreadsheets in the specified folder. How can this be done through looping?

Answer (score 0):

To loop through the files in one folder you'd do something like this. You can tweak this to include subfolders as well but it doesn't currently.

```
 function listFilesInFolder(folderName) {
  //modified from https://ctrlq.org/code/19854-list-files-in-google-drive-folder
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName).next();
  var contents = folder.getFiles();

  for (var i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {

    file = contents[i];

    if (file.getFileType() == "SPREADSHEET") {
      removeDuplicate(file.getId()); //get the ID and run the remove duplicates script on that particular ss   
    }        

  }
```

};

You'd change the original script to something like this.

```
function removeDuplicates(ssid) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssid);//now opening the various ss by ID
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss); //and making them the active ss
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var newData = new Array();
  for(i in data){
    var row = data[i];
    var duplicate = false;
    for(j in newData){
      if(row.join() == newData[j].join()){
        duplicate = true;
      }
    }
    if(!duplicate){
      newData.push(row);
    }
  }
  sheet.clearContents();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length)
      .setValues(newData);
}
```